# Barton-Nackman vs std::enable_if

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, template-meta-programming, c++-concepts

What is preferable (if any)?

Variant A (Barton-Nackman):

```
template<class T>
struct equal_comparable {
    friend bool operator == (const T & t1, const T & t2) {
        return t1.equalTo (t2);
    }
};

class MyClass : private equal_comparable<MyClass> {
    bool equalTo (const MyClass & other)  //...
};
```

Variant B (std::enable_if):

```
struct MyClass {
    static const bool use_my_equal = true;
    bool equalTo (const MyClass & other) //...
};

template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<
    T::use_my_equal,
    bool
>::type
operator == (const T & t1, const T & t2) { return t1.equalTo (t2); }
```

Comment: Personally I prefer the former. `equal_comparable` can be put into a suitable namespace, but who knows what the member `use_my_equal` is used for by some type `T` that you've never heard of. Of course this problem applies to other similar uses of `enable_if` -- just because a dependent name resolves doesn't *necessarily* mean the name is used for what you think it means, if you're pulling it out of a namespace you don't control. You could use a type trait instead.

Comment: Why use a template at all? Why not just `bool operator==(const MyClass&, /* etc */);?`

Comment: @GManNickG: I believe that the purpose of the trick is to reduce the boilerplate required per class that is equality-comparable.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Oh right. Never been a fan. :)

Comment: @GManNickG: Boost operators is somewhat more convincing, since there's actual information in the operator overloads that warrants re-use. They're not purely there to forward to one corresponding member function per operator.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Yeah. I just don't find myself writing all these operators that often, so when I do I write them all out. And if I needed a shortcut I'd use a macro (not a big fan of `boost::noncopyable` either, for example); I think in the end generating code with macros is cleaner than (ab)using templates andor inheritance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd prefer to use [Boost.Operators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/utility/operators.htm) mentioned by @SteveJessop in the comments, which formalizes and automates your first approach. They also take care of the empty base optimization if you happen to need multiple sets of operators (and hence would need multiple inheritance). It's not so much the savings in typing, but also the code documentation/enforcement value, since these bases classes are right at the front of the class interface. In that sense, it's a primitive way of Concepts.